# Scraping urls from xml file and scraping those urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

so I have an item I declared in my items.py file called ArtscraperItem.

```
import scrapy


class ArtscraperItem(scrapy.Item):
    # define the fields for your item here like:
    # name = scrapy.Field()
    date = scrapy.Field()
    date_str = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    title = scrapy.Field()
    art_content = scrapy.Field()
```

I am running this spider and gathering data from the xml file. However, I also need to get the urls from the xml file and then scrape those urls to get the content of the article and add it as item[art_content]. I saw something similar on stackoverflow, but they weren't using a previously declared item, so I didn't know how to use it. So, I need to get the content from the url I scraped and add it to my ArtscraperItem that I created in my parse method.

Thanks in advance.

The method in question and the second parse_article method which is supposed to scrape the collected url and return the article content.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import scrapy
from ArtScraper.items import ArtscraperItem

class PostSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    article = ""
    name = 'crawly'
    allowed_domains = ['bbc.com/arabic']

    start_urls = ['http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/arabic/rss.xml']

    def parse(self, response):
        articles = response.xpath('//channel/item')
        for article in articles:
            item = ArtscraperItem()
            item['date']= dt.today()
            item['date_str'] = article.xpath('pubDate/text()').extract_first()
            item['url'] = article.xpath('link/text()').extract_first()
            item['title'] = article.xpath('title/text()').extract_first()
            url = item['url']
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_article)
            yield item

    def parse_article(self, response):
        pars = response.xpath("//div[@class='story-body']/div[@class='story-body__inner']/p/text()").extract()
        article = '-'.join(pars)
        yield{
            'art_content': article
        }
```

The settings.py file

```
#Settings.py

BOT_NAME = 'ArtScraper'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['ArtScraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'ArtScraper.spiders'


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the 
user-agent
#USER_AGENT = 'ArtScraper (+http://www.yourdomain.com)'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 
16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download- 
delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = .25
RANDOMIZE_DOWNLOAD_DELAY=True
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#   'Accept': 
'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
#   'Accept-Language': 'en',
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'ArtScraper.middlewares.ArtscraperSpiderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader- 
middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    'ArtScraper.middlewares.ArtscraperDownloaderMiddleware': 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html    
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole': None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'ArtScraper.pipelines.MongoPipeline': 300,  
}
MONGO_URI='localhost:27017'
MONGO_DATABASE='george'

#Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel 
to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader- 
middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = 'httpcache'
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 
'scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage'
```

The pipelines.py file

```
import logging
import pymongo

class MongoPipeline(object):

collection_name = 'articles'

def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
    self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
    self.mongo_db = mongo_db

@classmethod
def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
    ## pull in information from settings.py
    return cls(
        mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
        mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE')
    )

def open_spider(self, spider):
    ## initializing spider
    ## opening db connection
    self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
    self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

def close_spider(self, spider):
    ## clean up when spider is closed
    self.client.close()

def process_item(self, item, spider):
    ## how to handle each post
    self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
    logging.debug("Post added to MongoDB")
    return item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called request chaining and meta carry over.
You have 2 requests to make 1 item, thus you need to:

1. Go to url A, gather some data
2. Go to url B, add more data
3. Return single Item with data from A and B

To link these two steps you can use `Request.meta` attribute, like so:

```
def parse(self, response):
    articles = response.xpath('//channel/item')
    for article in articles:
        item = ArtscraperItem()
        ...
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url, 
            callback=self.parse_article,
            meta={'item': item},  # carry over our item
        )

def parse_article(self, response):
    # retrieve carried over item
    item = response.meta['item']
    pars = response.xpath("//div[@class='story-body']/div[@class='story-body__inner']/p/text()").extract()
    item['art_content'] = '-'.join(pars)
    yield item
```

Comment: In this case, do I also have to change my pipelines.py file or settings.py file since I was yielding items at the end of my parse file, but now I'm yielding scrapy.Request instead. Sorry if this is a bit of a noobish question, but this is a bit new to me and your method still didn't add the content of the article to the collection of my database. I've added settings and pipelines to my post if you need to see them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok I modified my pipelines.py file, I will include the new pipelines file in the edit later, but your method worked perfectly. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @HadiNounou to clarify - scrapy pipelines don't receive `Request` objects, _only_ `Item` objects. `Request` objects that are being generated go to scrapy's downloader and continue the crawl.